# Truth in programming and life

Tags: logic, truth

I am a python beginner and noticed that True + True > True

Do True and False have a different meaning in computer logic than in life? 
Or should I consider this same statement as true in life?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. I like your question, but I am not sure where you arrive at consideration this might apply to life.

Comment: I was playing on scratch with a model of a fictitious universe where matter and antimatter was randomly added. I was wondering if I could just change the word universe for the word existence and randomly add true or false to the statement " I exist" . It is just a thought process, I am  neither philosopher nor computer programmer , just curious.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. When you use `+` or `>`, the value is cast to a type that has these operations, in this case `int`. True is cast to 1, so you get 1 + 1 > 1, which is true because 2 > 1. This is a representational issue: had we represented True with 0, it would not have worked. Had we worked with one-bit integers, 1 + 1 would overflow to 0, and 0 < 1 so True + True < 1. In the end, it is hard to link this computer artefact to "life". It is unclear to me what you mean by "is true + true greater than true *in life*", or how it is an answerable question as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: In a [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), where the truth values are modelled with 0 and 1, the "basic" [operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations) are redefined.

Comment: Statement 1 ; It is true.  
Statement 2 ; It is true and it is true.
  Statement 1a ; It is true and it is false.
  Statement 2a; It is true and (it is true and it is false)
If statement 1 and statement 2 are the same thing then statement 1a and 2a must be the same. I feel statement 1a is statement of less truth than statement 2a therefore statement 1 must be less true than statement 2.
It is more a gut feeling  but this example springs to mind: "I exist within an existence that both exists and doesn't exist" is different to "I exist and don't exist"

Comment: You're mixing types. True/false is a logical type which has no addition operation, at least not in classical logic. For something like Zadeh's fuzzy logic, truth values can be any real between 0 and 1, and can be more-or-less added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a strict programming scenario where "True" is treated as a variable, and not in any philosophical way. For example in VBA "True" is equivalent to -1, while False is equivalent to 0. Other programming languages define "True" as 1. If that is the case with Python, it follows that 1 + 1 > 1.

In Philosophy, True + True = True because Truth is not a divisible value.